# Create re-usable text snippets in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

Is it possible to create re-usable text snippets in OneNote 2010?

I often find myself writing the same text. Being able to bind the insertion of configurable text to a key combination would be very useful.

Is this possible or is there an Addin that can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't insist on doing this via an addin (why would you?), using AutoHotkey hotstrings solves the general problem.

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem, thank you. It's a bit tricky if I want to do formatting etc but is possible at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/a/475672/177531 provides an idea. But the text snippets would have to be "bound" to a tiny piece of typed text rather than to hotkeys.

Go to File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options. Place the "shortcut" in the Replace: box and the snippet in the With: box.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page template, which is re-usable. This only works for creating a new page, and not in the general "cut-and-paste" sense. The option is under Insert > Page Templates.