# How to insert a html type separator line in a OneNote page?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

If such functionality is at all offered by this software.

I'm talking about `<hr>` Horizontal Rule.

Currently using OneNote 2013 Preview, if this makes a difference.

Comment: why not just `---------------------------------` or `______________________`?

Answer (score 24):

Per discussion @ http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-onenote/suggestion-add-insert-horizontal-line/498fe78c-93c3-4f38-9ffd-c720c605aad4 it seems to not be supported, though someone noted a hack:

File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options 
enter three underscore characters; in the Replace field enter a large number underscore chars.

Thus, entering three underscore chars and pressing enter gives you (almost) a horizontal line.

Comment: I think it's easier to set the autocorrect trigger to 3 minus characters so you don't have to hold down shift every time you want the horizontal rule.

Comment: @ChrisB - True but I wonder is worth breaking convention, expectation and consistency i.e. one trigger for Word and another OneNote.

Comment: Note that because the auto-correct option is used across all Office apps, it breaks the standard behavior in Word to replace "---" or "___" with a real horizontal line.

Answer (score 5):

Onetastic, an extension of OneNote, allows "Insert Horizontal Line" functionality by way of macro:

http://www.omeratay.com/onetastic/?r=downloadMacro&id=0B63F5F2A5EA41F1952B45D0E80402EC

Regarding the preview version of OneNote you referenced, you're may or may not be aware by now that OneNote (2013) is now free. The only limitation to the free version is that notebooks can only be saved to your OneDrive account and not locally.

OneDrive, by default, grants 15GB free which is decently sufficient for most notebook types and should you require the next level up, 100 GB will cost you €1.99 a month.

https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-ie/plans

Comment: Of course Onetastic. Why I have not thought about it before looking this up? This is the only extension I have and it shows why.

Answer (score 3):

A better way of inserting the line may be this one: 
Create a GIF image file of size 2x2 pixel. fill the image file with grey color or any other color you would like your line to be. Save the image.
Insert the image in the onenote. Now resize the image to a horizontal line. it is easy to drag and move the line as well.
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Insert an empty `1x1` Table as follows

[image]

Right click on it and select the bucket tool to fill it with your preferred color.

The advantage of this solution, with respect with the simple ones with individual characters, is that this bar can be resized easily, and it moves with the text as one would expect.

The result is the following

[image]

Answer (score 1):

98 underscores in a line in OneNote with Calibri @ Font 11 (the Default), that is exactly one whole line of the default width before it wraps around.

Here are 98 of them for you:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Copy that line text

Do what **jhstuckey** said:

> File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options enter three underscore characters; in the Replace field enter a large number underscore chars.

Can also put --- (3 dashes or 4 or whatever you like) in the left and paste the underscores on the right.  Click Add.

---

**Slightly Advanced Additional line.**

Put === (3 equals signs) on the left and copy and paste the double lines in from below on the right.

```
‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗‗
```

The double lines can be found in charmap (type that in the start menu search) on the Calibri Font.

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the charmap characters, scroll back up 4 full pages, it's in the second row just to the right of center.

Comment: I don't see `File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options` in OneNote from Windows store...

Comment: @Kirby, there are two varieties of OneNote - the free version available for everyone with Windows, and the version that is part of Office. This feature is only available in the Office version.

Answer (score 1):

Onetastic has a macro for inserting a horizontal line: https://getonetastic.com/macroland&id=0B63F5F2A5EA41F1952B45D0E80402EC

I use that.

Comment: Links to third-party resources are not welcomed as an answer since the link could stop work in any moment.

Answer (score 1):

PankajSays method works well.

[image: Horizontal line as PNG]

Paste it in and resize it. It is attached as text and moves up/down as the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

Searched for an answer, found this, then found the answer myself.

Outlook 2010 here:
Switch to the Draw tab.
In Insert Shapes Ribbon Bar tab, select the diagonal straight line, no errors, etc.
Draw a short line as horizontal as possible. Click and drag it to just below a line of text and it will snap to the bottom of the line, exactly horizontal.
Then click the right-hand drag handle and extend it.
 - L

Comment: That's not a good solution, because the drawn line is not _inline_ with the text, meaning that the drawn line does not move downward if you add text above it

Answer (score 0):

Additional information:

Inserting a line by using "Draw", "Shapes" will certainly insert a line in a OneNote document. BUT the line is not recognized as text... so if your OneNote document includes text, and you add more text, the drawn line *WILL NOT* scroll with the text.

Mentioning this because I was also trying to insert dividing lines in a OneNote text document and had this experience. Seems like the best way to go is just making lines of text as suggested above.

### _____________________________

=================

Answer (score 0):

I used a single cell table, filled with '_' and then hid the borders.

[use table, hide borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0RBP.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I found and used.

First, install a OneNote Add-in named OneMore:
https://github.com/stevencohn/OneMore#-onemore---a-onenote-add-in

Second, use the "Snippets commands" and insert a single or double "horizontal line":
https://github.com/stevencohn/OneMore/wiki/Snippets-Commands

Finally, the page you used will be inserted a single or double horizontal line which consists of [Box Drawings Light Horizontal](https://unicode-table.com/en/2500/) or [Box Drawings Double Horizontal](https://unicode-table.com/en/2550/) characters.